# Display the image in the loop by clicking the button with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-core

I have a loop that displays three images
this loop :

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <img id="img" src="@item.imgname" />
                            }
```

so I have three buttons :

```
<div class="box-img">
     <a class="btn btn-success">First pic</a>
     <a class="btn btn-info">second pic</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary">third pic</a>
 </div>
```

When the "First pic" tag is clicked, the first image is displayed and the "second pic" tag is clicked, the second image is displayed and ...

How can I doing?

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor.

Comment: show your attempt

Comment: I could not write the code

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I Have Loop How I Select Image in Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Display the image in the loop by clicking the button with jquery

You can refer to the following code snippet to achieve the requirement.

HTML code

```
<div id="img_container">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <img id="img" src="@item.imgname" />
    }
</div>

<hr />

<div class="box-img">
    <a class="btn btn-success">First pic</a>
    <a class="btn btn-info">second pic</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary">third pic</a>
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
$(function () {
    //hide all these three images
    $("div#img_container img").hide();

    //display the first image
    $("div#img_container img:nth-child(1)").show();

    //display the first image
    $("a.btn-success").click(function () {
        $("div#img_container img").hide();

        $("div#img_container img:nth-child(1)").show();
    });

    //display the second image
    $("a.btn-info").click(function () {
        $("div#img_container img").hide();

        $("div#img_container img:nth-child(2)").show();
    });

    //display the third image
    $("a.btn-primary").click(function () {
        $("div#img_container img").hide();

        $("div#img_container img:nth-child(3)").show();
    })
})
```

Test Result

[image]